# Scaling seems to crop edges of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm doing some automation with FFmpeg and I need to be able to scale up and down videos. So I tried using the scale filter. No issue when I'm scaling up but when I'm scaling down I'm losing a few pixels from the bottom of the video and I must keep everything.

Here is an example:

```
$ ffmpeg.exe -i video.avi -vf scale=1536:644 video_resized.avi
```

Here, video.avi is 2048x858.
I tried a lot of parameters, algorithms and flags but nothing seems to "fix" it. Maybe it is normal and I'm not understanding correctly how scaling works but I need to resize without loss of edges.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect ffmpeg to do. But by scaling down you will definitely lose some data. As you are trying to represent more pixels with less.

What you can do is modifying the scaling algorithm by adding the `flags` option to scale.

docs:

- [flag options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html#sws_005fflags)
- [scale docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1)